# SVN tree conflicts subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am running Eclipse Version: 3.5.2
Subclipse 1.6.10

I had a Branch (b) which I forked (f1, f2) and then made a merge branch (m) so I could do incremental merges.
After all that I added a new directory in b so it would flow through both forks into m. Now when I try to merge that directory into m I get a tree conflict.

I have been using the "Merge a range of revisions" options in the subclipse dialog.

The subfolders and files from the conflict are not being brought forward.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up committing what was left and sorting out the mess by hand. There were only 3 files involved so it wasn't a huge deal.